# Список связанных элементов MYSQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Мне нужно написать запрос в котором один обращённый элемент будет выводить в одной ячейке, список связанных с ним элементов, из другой таблицы.

Есть элемент №1 с ним в связи состоят как минимум 3 элемента, мне 3 элемента нужно вывести списком в ячейке. Как это сделать?
№1 -1
№1 -2
№1 -3 и нужно вывести в Select (1,2,3)

Comment: GROUP BY + GROUP_CONCAT()

Comment: А если значений очень много, то как по одному экземпляру взять?

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Добавьте CREATE TABLE, INSERT INTO с данными и требуемый для этих данных результат.